# C# Path not recognized or utilized when invoking File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I’m trying to use the File class to work with a text file in a console and winforms desktop app and getting the following exception:
The type initializer for '_Library.Logging' threw an exception

From what I’ve read here this error is typically caused by a problem in App.config for Winfoms apps but the Exception details seem to point elsewhere:

System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: path

at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String contents)

The MSDN examples for file manipulation all hard code the path parameter without any reference to using an App.confiig file so my presumption was it is possible to do this without involving ConfigurationManager.

This is the code I'm trying to use

```
// in calling method
class Program_Console
{
    private static StringBuilder SB4log = new StringBuilder();
    public static void Main(string[] tsArgs)
    {
        // Conditionals dealing with argumentts from Task Scheduler
        Save2Log("Calling _UI.exe via \"Process.Start()\"", true);
        // try-catch-finally for Process.Start
    }
    private static void Save2Log(string msgTxt, bool noTS)
    {
        SB4log.AppendLine($"{msgTxt}");
        if (noTS) Logging.SaveLog(SB4log);
        else Logging.SaveLog_TimeStamp(SB4log);
        SB4log.Clear();
    }
}

// saving app progression messages to a single log txt file
public static class Logging
{
    private static String filePath = Connections.LogPath();
    private static StringBuilder SB4log = new StringBuilder();

    public static void SaveLog(StringBuilder logTxt)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, logTxt.ToString());
        logTxt.Clear();
    }
}
    
// class for DB connection and file paths
public static class Connections
{
    private static StringBuilder SB4log = new StringBuilder();
    public static string AppPath()
    {
        string appRoot;
        try
        {
            string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            SaveLog($"->App Path: {appDir}", true);  // culprit
            int loc = appDir.IndexOf("BURS");
            appRoot = appDir.Substring(0, loc + 5);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
        // Exception response and MessageBox
        }
        return appRoot;
    }
    public static string ConsolePath() {}
    public static string UIPath() {}
    public static string LogPath()
    {
        string appRoot = AppPath();
        string wrkDir = @"_Library\Data\BURS_Log.Txt";
        string fullDir = $"{appRoot}{wrkDir}";
        SaveLog($"->Log Path: {fullDir}\n", true); // culprit
        return fullDir;
    }
}
```

In stepping through the code the code the variable containing the path -- filePath -- has the expected value: "D:\BURS_Library\Data\BURS_Log.Txt" (quotes used to  show there re no unintended spaces needing to be trimmed).   Acordinng to MSDN if it's a malformed path an exception will be thrown but the path looks valid to me.

Why isn’t the Path variable utilized?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: expanded code to show start-to-finish flow since the original abridged version seemed to be confusing.  Have added the text "//culprit" to the two lines which caused the error as pointed out by the responders.

Comment: Looks like the call to `SaveLog` within `AppPath` would attempt to access `filePath` before it has been set. Additionally, your calls to `SaveLog` have a different parameters than the method you posted, so I don't think this is your actual code or we're missing something. Also, if this isn't just an academic exercise, I'd recommend using an established logging library like `ILogger` for .net core or NLog for .net framework.

Comment: @Jason P Thanks for the response. No, it's not an academic exercise. I've now done some research the logging frameworks NLog, log4net and Serilog but they looked like they are intended for use in fairly complex high volume environments.  Are they also applicable for a simple desktop app (only about 20 forms) with only one envisioned log file?

Comment: Yes, I'd use an established library even for simple applications. These libraries do seem a bit overwhelming at first, but the hour (at the most) you spend reading the docs to get NLog to output a simple log file is probably less time than you'll spend writing and debugging your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what `Connections` is, but given `Connections.LogPath();` it seems that you're calling `LogPath();` to set the value for `filePath` which is a problem because that calls `AppPath` which has the following statement `SaveLog($"->App Path: {appDir}", true);`.

You haven't included a version of `SaveLog` that has 2 parameters, but assuming it's similar to the one you've posted, you're attempting to use `filePath` when the value hasn't been set yet - which causes an issue.

Comment: Thank you. Deleted the "SaveLog"  calls in the middle of defining the save to paths.  Problem solved.